# how to implemant image map in flexslider?

Tags: hyperlink, flexslider, imagemap

I am using flexslider.
It is very easy to implement and  customizing.

Now my every slide is a link.
is there any way to put to links for a single slide?

that needs to redirect to PAGE1 when click the left side of the image and must redirect to PAGE2 when click the right side.

Thanks in advance dear seniors...

**I've found the answer**.
The following method is working

```
<div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
              <!-- slide1 -->
                <li>
                    <img src="images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" usemap="#map2" />
                    <map name="map2">
                        <area shape="rect" coords="494,2,961,745" href="http://www.john-anthony.com/mens/jeans/" alt=""/>
                        <area shape="rect" coords="0,4,482,749" href="http://www.john-anthony.com/vivienne-westwood/blazer-jackets/burgundy/jacket-waistcoat-check/vw024-a13-bur/" alt=""/>
                    </map>

                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @VijetaShetty thanks for the interest.
I've found the way.
Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've found the answer.** The following method is working

```
<div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
              <!-- slide1 -->
                <li>
                    <img src="images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" usemap="#map2" />
                    <map name="map2">
                        <area shape="rect" coords="494,2,961,745" href="http://www.john-anthony.com/mens/jeans/" alt=""/>
                        <area shape="rect" coords="0,4,482,749" href="http://www.john-anthony.com/vivienne-westwood/blazer-jackets/burgundy/jacket-waistcoat-check/vw024-a13-bur/" alt=""/>
                    </map>

                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```